# Does the alchemy of souls require Hwansu?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

On the one hand, when discussing the alchemy of souls, the masters of Songrim seem to say that it requires Hwansu, the ability to turn water into fire, and that even though this may seem to be a power limited to the gods, their founder and one other person managed it (this would possibly be Teacher Lee, since he implied that he could teach Jang-Wook Hwansu and Nak-su said that he had clearly surpassed the higher levels of the ability directly below Hwansu).

On the other hand, we have seen that both Nak-su and Jang Gang are capable of transferring their souls to another body, and the Songrim masters knew this, so there seems to be a contradiction if Hwansu is required to carry out the transfer.

Is Hwansu required for the alchemy of souls, or only to maintain stability after performing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As revealed in later episodes, the answer to this question is that the ice stone grants the powers of Hwansu itself, and beyond that—or possibly as a consequence—allows the user to create the Soul Ejector, a sort of black powder that allows mages without any talent for Hwansu, or perhaps even non-mages, to shift their soul. As such, Hwansu *is* normally required for the alchemy of souls, but it can be a sort of artificial, even second-hand Hwansu.

Jin Mu has stores of Soul Ejectors, and since Naksu was acting under his orders, he presumably gave her some in order to make a quick escape if necessary (and as a motivator). It is all but certain that Naksu does not know Hwansu, both because its extreme difficulty means that almost no one has achieved it, and because she would not be at risk of running wild if she knew it, which she appears to think is a possibility. Jang Gang presumably had the ice stone at the time he transferred his soul, meaning that he probably did not know Hwansu, either, although it is impossible to completely rule out the possibility that he might have.

However, it *is* confirmed that Teacher Lee knows Hwansu, since he used it to transfer his soul to another body.